# Match-3 game - match dependent sounds

Tags: python, pygame

I'm looking to get some help with a match-3 game I'm working on in pygame. I've loaded the images and sounds as follows and the 'gems' will be the classical elements air, earth, fire and water. How can I play the appropriate water sound file, for example, when 3 or more water sprites are matched? Don't need help with any of the game code just to create an association between the image and audio files and how to play it 'while matchedElements != []'. Thank you.

```
# Directions
UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

# Space to the sides of grid
XMARGIN = int((WIDTH - ELEMENTSIZE * GRIDWIDTH) / 2)
YMARGIN = int((HEIGHT - ELEMENTSIZE * GRIDHEIGHT) / 2)

EMPTY_SPACE = -1
ROWABOVEBOARD = 'row above board'

# Colours
AIR = pygame.Color(145, 129, 129)
FIRE = pygame.Color(255, 123, 0)
WATER = pygame.Color(93, 118, 245)
EARTH = pygame.Color(22, 136, 0)
ELECTRIC = pygame.Color(22, 204, 0)
SMOKE = pygame.Color(222, 222, 222)
ICE = pygame.Color(234, 231, 255)
METAL = pygame.Color(105, 105, 105)
BLOOD = pygame.Color(222, 7, 7)

# FPS controller
fpsController = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, BOARDRECTS, ELEMENTIMAGES, SOUNDS, PLAYSURF, BASICFONT

    # Basic set up
    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    PLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 36)

    # Load images
    ELEMENTIMAGES = []
    for i in range(1, NUMELEMENTS+1):
        elementImage = pygame.image.load('element%s.jpg' % i)
        if elementImage.get_size() != (ELEMENTSIZE, ELEMENTSIZE):
            elementImage = pygame.transform.smoothscale(elementImage, (ELEMENTSIZE, ELEMENTSIZE))
        ELEMENTIMAGES.append(elementImage)

    # Load sounds
    SOUNDS = {}
    SOUNDS['bad swap'] = pygame.mixer.Sound('badswap.wav')
    SOUNDS['match'] = []
    for i in range(NUMMATCHSOUNDS):
        SOUNDS['match'].append(pygame.mixer.Sound('elementsound%s.wav' % i))

    # Rect objects for board space conversions
    BOARDRECTS = []
    for x in range(GRIDWIDTH):
        BOARDRECTS.append([])
        for y in range(GRIDHEIGHT):
            r = pygame.Rect((XMARGIN + (x * ELEMENTSIZE),
                             YMARGIN + (y * ELEMENTSIZE),
                             ELEMENTSIZE, ELEMENTSIZE))
            BOARDRECTS[x].append(r)

    while True:
        runGame()

def runGame():
    # Board initialisation
    gameBoard = getBlankBoard()
    score = 0
    fillBoardAndAnimate(gameBoard, [], score) # Drop initial elements

    # Initialise new game variables
    firstSelectedElement = None
    lastMouseDownX = None
    lastMouseDownY = None
    gameIsOver = False
    lastScoreDeduction = time.time()
    clickContinueTextSurf = None

    # Main game loop
    while True:
        clickedSpace = None
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # Event handling
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                return # new game

            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if gameIsOver:
                    return # click to start new game

                if event.pos == (lastMouseDownX, lastMouseDownY):
                    clickedSpace = checkForElementClick(event.pos)
                else:
                    firstSelectedElement = checkForElementClick((lastMouseDownX, lastMouseDownY))
                    clickedSpace = checkForElementClick(event.pos)
                    if not firstSelectedElement or not clickedSpace:
                        firstSelectedElement = None
                        clickedSpace = None
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                lastMouseDownX, lastMouseDownY = event.pos

        if clickedSpace and not firstSelectedElement:
            firstSelectedElement = clickedSpace
        elif clickedSpace and firstSelectedElement:
            firstSwappingElement, secondSwappingElement = getSwappingElements(gameBoard, firstSelectedElement, clickedSpace)
            if firstSwappingElement == None and secondSwappingElement == None:
                # If both are None, elements are not adjacent
                firstSelectedElement = None
                continue

            # Swap animation
            boardCopy = getBoardCopyMinusElements(gameBoard, (firstSwappingElement, secondSwappingElement))
            animateMovingElements(boardCopy, [firstSwappingElement, secondSwappingElement], [], score)

            # Swap elements in the board
            gameBoard[firstSwappingElement['x']][firstSwappingElement['y']] = secondSwappingElement['imageNum']
            gameBoard[secondSwappingElement['x']][secondSwappingElement['y']] = firstSwappingElement['imageNum']

            # See if this is a match
            matchedElements = findMatchingElements(gameBoard)
            if matchedElements == []:
                # No match - swap back
                SOUNDS['bad swap'].play()
                animateMovingElements(boardCopy, [firstSwappingElement, secondSwappingElement], [], score)
                gameBoard[firstSwappingElement['x']][firstSwappingElement['y']] = firstSwappingElement['imageNum']
                gameBoard[secondSwappingElement['x']][secondSwappingElement['y']] = secondSwappingElement['imageNum']
            else:
                # A match
                scoreAdd = 0
                while matchedElements != []:
                    points = []
                    for elementSet in matchedElements:
                        scoreAdd += (10 + (len(elementSet) - 3) * 10)
                        for element in elementSet:
                            gameBoard[element[0]][element[1]] = EMPTY_SPACE
                        points.append({'points': scoreAdd,
                                       'x': element[0] * ELEMENTSIZE + XMARGIN,
                                       'y': element[1] * ELEMENTSIZE + YMARGIN})
                    score += scoreAdd

                    # Drop new elements
                    fillBoardAndAnimate(gameBoard, points, score)

                    # Check for new matches
                    matchedElements = findMatchingElements(gameBoard)
            firstSelectedElement = None

            if not canMakeMove(gameBoard):
                gameIsOver = True

        # Draw the board
        PLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOUR)
        drawBoard(gameBoard)
        if firstSelectedElement != None:
            highlightSpace(firstSelectedElement['x'], firstSelectedElement['y'])
        if gameIsOver:
            if clickContinueTextSurf == None:
                clickContinueTextSurf = BASICFONT.render('Final Score: %s (Click to continue)' % (score), 1, GAMEOVERCOLOUR, GAMEOVERBGCOLOUR)
                clickContinueTextRect = clickContinueTextSurf.get_rect()
                clickContinueTextRect.center = int(WIDTH / 2), int(HEIGHT / 2)
            PLAYSURF.blit(clickContinueTextSurf, clickContinueTextRect)
        elif score > 0 and time.time() - lastScoreDeduction > DEDUCTSPEED:
            # score drops over time
            score -= 1
            lastScoreDeduction = time.time()
        drawScore(score)
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)                

def getSwappingElements(board, firstXY, secondXY):
    # If the elements at the (X, Y) coordinates of the two elements are adjacent,
    # then their 'direction' keys are set to the appropriate direction
    # value to be swapped with each other.
    # Otherwise, (None, None) is returned.
    firstElement = {'imageNum': board[firstXY['x']][firstXY['y']],
                'x': firstXY['x'],
                'y': firstXY['y']}
    secondElement = {'imageNum': board[secondXY['x']][secondXY['y']],
                 'x': secondXY['x'],
                 'y': secondXY['y']}
    highlightedElement = None
    if firstElement['x'] == secondElement['x'] + 1 and firstElement['y'] == secondElement['y']:
        firstElement['direction'] = LEFT
        secondElement['direction'] = RIGHT
    elif firstElement['x'] == secondElement['x'] - 1 and firstElement['y'] == secondElement['y']:
        firstElement['direction'] = RIGHT
        secondElement['direction'] = LEFT
    elif firstElement['y'] == secondElement['y'] + 1 and firstElement['x'] == secondElement['x']:
        firstElement['direction'] = UP
        secondElement['direction'] = DOWN
    elif firstElement['y'] == secondElement['y'] - 1 and firstElement['x'] == secondElement['x']:
        firstElement['direction'] = DOWN
        secondElement['direction'] = UP
    else:
        # These elements are not adjacent and can't be swapped.
        return None, None
    return firstElement, secondElement

def getBlankBoard():
    # Create and return a blank board data structure.
    board = []
    for x in range(GRIDWIDTH):
        board.append([EMPTY_SPACE] * GRIDHEIGHT)
    return board

def canMakeMove(board):
    # Return True if the board is in a state where a matching
    # move can be made on it. Otherwise return False.

    # The patterns in oneOffPatterns represent elements that are configured
    # in a way where it only takes one move to make a triplet.
    oneOffPatterns = (((0,1), (1,0), (2,0)),
                      ((0,1), (1,1), (2,0)),
                      ((0,0), (1,1), (2,0)),
                      ((0,1), (1,0), (2,1)),
                      ((0,0), (1,0), (2,1)),
                      ((0,0), (1,1), (2,1)),
                      ((0,0), (0,2), (0,3)),
                      ((0,0), (0,1), (0,3)))

    # The x and y variables iterate over each space on the board.
    # If we use + to represent the currently iterated space on the
    # board, then this pattern: ((0,1), (1,0), (2,0))refers to identical
    # elements being set up like this:
    #
    #     +A
    #     B
    #     C
    #
    # That is, element A is offset from the + by (0,1), element B is offset
    # by (1,0), and element C is offset by (2,0). In this case, element A can
    # be swapped to the left to form a vertical three-in-a-row triplet.
    #
    # There are eight possible ways for the elements to be one move
    # away from forming a triple, hence oneOffPattern has 8 patterns.

    for x in range(GRIDWIDTH):
        for y in range(GRIDHEIGHT):
            for pat in oneOffPatterns:
                # check each possible pattern of "match in next move" to
                # see if a possible move can be made.
                if (getElementAt(board, x+pat[0][0], y+pat[0][1]) == \
                    getElementAt(board, x+pat[1][0], y+pat[1][1]) == \
                    getElementAt(board, x+pat[2][0], y+pat[2][1]) != None) or \
                   (getElementAt(board, x+pat[0][1], y+pat[0][0]) == \
                    getElementAt(board, x+pat[1][1], y+pat[1][0]) == \
                    getElementAt(board, x+pat[2][1], y+pat[2][0]) != None):
                    return True # return True the first time you find a pattern
    return False

def drawMovingElement(element, progress):
    # Draw an element sliding in the direction that its 'direction' key
    # indicates. The progress parameter is a number from 0 (just
    # starting) to 100 (slide complete).
    movex = 0
    movey = 0
    progress *= 0.01

    if element['direction'] == UP:
        movey = -int(progress * ELEMENTSIZE)
    elif element['direction'] == DOWN:
        movey = int(progress * ELEMENTSIZE)
    elif element['direction'] == RIGHT:
        movex = int(progress * ELEMENTSIZE)
    elif element['direction'] == LEFT:
        movex = -int(progress * ELEMENTSIZE)

    basex = element['x']
    basey = element['y']
    if basey == ROWABOVEBOARD:
        basey = -1

    pixelx = XMARGIN + (basex * ELEMENTSIZE)
    pixely = YMARGIN + (basey * ELEMENTSIZE)
    r = pygame.Rect( (pixelx + movex, pixely + movey, ELEMENTSIZE, ELEMENTSIZE) )
    PLAYSURF.blit(ELEMENTIMAGES[element['imageNum']], r)

def pullDownAllElements(board):
    # pulls down elements on the board to the bottom to fill in any gaps
    for x in range(GRIDWIDTH):
        elementsInColumn = []
        for y in range(GRIDHEIGHT):
            if board[x][y] != EMPTY_SPACE:
                elementsInColumn.append(board[x][y])
        board[x] = ([EMPTY_SPACE] * (GRIDHEIGHT - len(elementsInColumn))) + elementsInColumn

def getElementAt(board, x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= GRIDWIDTH or y >= GRIDHEIGHT:
        return None
    else:
        return board[x][y]

def getDropSlots(board):
    # Creates a "drop slot" for each column and fills the slot with a
    # number of elements that that column is lacking. This function assumes
    # that the elements have been gravity dropped already.
    boardCopy = copy.deepcopy(board)
    pullDownAllElements(boardCopy)

    dropSlots = []
    for i in range(GRIDWIDTH):
        dropSlots.append([])

    # count the number of empty spaces in each column on the board
    for x in range(GRIDWIDTH):
        for y in range(GRIDHEIGHT-1, -1, -1): # start from bottom, going up
            if boardCopy[x][y] == EMPTY_SPACE:
                possibleElements = list(range(len(ELEMENTIMAGES)))
                for offsetX, offsetY in ((0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0)):
                    # Narrow down the possible elements we should put in the
                    # blank space so we don't end up putting an two of
                    # the same elements next to each other when they drop.
                    neighborElement = getElementAt(boardCopy, x + offsetX, y + offsetY)
                    if neighborElement != None and neighborElement in possibleElements:
                        possibleElements.remove(neighborElement)

                newElement = random.choice(possibleElements)
                boardCopy[x][y] = newElement
                dropSlots[x].append(newElement)
    return dropSlots
```

Comment: How do you check if 3 or more sprites match?

Comment: I've edited the question to include that code.

Comment: What's in the `gameBoard`?

Comment: def getBlankBoard():
    # Create and return a blank board data structure.
    board = []
    for x in range(GRIDWIDTH):
        board.append([EMPTY_SPACE] * GRIDHEIGHT)
    return board

Comment: That function is stored in the gameBoard

Comment: And do you fill it with the images or any values that represent the different elements?

Comment: You could probably associate the elements in the `gameBoard` with the sounds. Create a dictionary with the elements as the keys and the corresponding sounds as the values. When you have a match, just check which element it was and look it up in the dictionary to get the sound.

Comment: Just tried the dictionary but it says list is unhashable, I guess because I've uploaded the sounds in a list? I've noticed that if I add the line of code 'random.choice(SOUNDS['match']).play()' it will play 1 of the four sounds, when any match is made, does that help? Can that line of code be altered to take advantage of the fact the file names are numbered? Water being 'element1.jpg' and the water sound being  'elementsound1.wav'

Comment: Take a look at my answer and try to do something similar. I'm not sure what exactly you're doing and what the `gameBoard` contains, so I can't provide more help (unless you add more details to the question).

Comment: Sorry didn't see the other comment, I've just edited to include all the code, cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a partial answer to demonstrate what I suggested in the comments. I'm not sure how your `gameBoard` actually looks like, so you have to adjust the code as needed.

I use a board which is just filled with strings in this example (you could also use constants `WATER = 1`, `FIRE = 2`, etc. or an enum). The sounds are in a dictionary with the elements as the keys. If you have a match, figure out which element it is, then use it to get the associated sound out of the dict and play it.

```
ELEMENT_SOUNDS = {
    'water': WATER_SOUND,
    'fire': FIRE_SOUND,
    }

board = [
    ['water', 'fire', 'water'],
    ['fire', 'water', 'fire'],
    ['water', 'water', 'water'],
    ]

if match:
    # Figure out the kind of the matching element 'water' in this case.
    element_kind = 'water'
    ELEMENT_SOUNDS[element_kind].play()
```